# spring aop advice controller failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

Controller:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("rest/test/api")
public class TestApiController {

    private LogApiService logApiService;
    private LogApiController logApiController;
    public TestApiController(LogApiService las, LogApiController lac) {
        this.logApiService = las;
        this.logApiController = lac;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity config(@RequestBody LogConfigDTO dto) {
        return logApiController.config(dto);
    }
```

Aspect:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestApiControllerAop {

    private ApiProperties apiProperties;

    public TestApiControllerAop(ApiProperties apiProperties) {
        this.apiProperties = apiProperties;
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.demo.TestApiController.*(..)) " +
        "&& @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void beforeRequestMappingAnnotatedMethod() {
        boolean isDebug = apiProperties.getLog().isDebug();
        log.info("debug flag is" + isDebug);
        if (!isDebug) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test api controller debug mode is turned off");
        }
    }
}
```

Result: beans supposed to be injected but failed, both `LogApiService` and `LogApiController` objects are null. Besides, `@Before` method did not run. Although I can see TestApiController is marked as `EnhancerBySpringCGLIB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is private access level in controller! change it to public solves the problem. applicationContext.getBean(xx.class) would show [image]

which is exactly how it interprets when a `pointcut` targeted method is `private`: all injected fields are null. I guess this is because when it is private, the controller bean is taken out from the same place as `applicationContext.getBean()` while when it is `public`, the controller bean is a different one. I have just tried it with

```
@GetMapping("get")
private void get() {
    log.info("");
}
```

it is not pointcut targeted, but it sees the same as picture. Controller is like Service, while called, usually it is a public method, which is like a rule. On the other hand, controller private method could be also called from browser, making this rule "broken". The conclusion is that no matter a method is aop targeted or not, if it is able to be called through browser, it has to be a public method.

Comment: Yes, and this is well-documented in the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop). :-)

Comment: @kriegaex is `@RequestMapping` like annotations are also implemented using AOP technique? Why their methods can be private?

Comment: Interesting question. Actually, I am not a Spring user, just an AOP expert with AspectJ being my sweet spot. So if `@RequestMapping` does work with private methods, I conclude that it was not implemented internally via Spring AOP and probably not via AOP at all. Theoretically it could have been implemented with AspectJ, though, because AspectJ can intercept private methods. But then the AspectJ runtime would be mandatory as a dependency, even without using Spring AOP. AFAIK, this is not the case, I was just mentioning the theoretical option FYI.

Comment: Besides, I do not understand why anyone in a (RESTful) architecture would map any type of request to a private method, as HTTP request methods by definition comprise the public API of a RESTful component. So you do not want to do that anyway.

Comment: @kriegaex why RESTful component must have public methods as its API implementation?

Comment: I explained it above: A component in software development is by definition an isolated black box which can only be interacted with from outside via an API. In order for an API to be usable by anyone, its methods should be public. Only internal methods should be none-public, RESTful or not.So if you map an URI to a private method, IMO this is a design flaw because anyone who can play around and guess the URI can manipulate the component from outside via a private method. So in reality the method is not that private. Just make it public then or do not map it to an URI.